# Unable to complete installation of June 2012 CU for SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, cumulative-update

We have a four server farm. After laying down the bits for the June 2012 CU on all four servers, our system administrator began to run PSCONFIG on each of the four servers (I know, I know...) None of them ever truly successfully completed.

Now that the damage has been done, PSCONFIG will run to 100% on each of the four servers but "completes with errors" every time. The upgrade logs reveal no specific errors. Sometimes, the failure will be an SPUpgradeConcurrencyException that another upgrade session is in progress and an update conflict occurred.

After completion, Central Administration will show "No action required" for each of the servers on which PSCONFIG has been run, but after a restart, the servers will again show "Upgrade available" as though the CU had never been successfully applied. We have seen other problems in conjunction with this, such as search crawls not running as scheduled even though the timer jobs are there.

In running the STSADM -o localupgradestatus checks, none of the content databases in the farm appear to need upgrading. There are 3 sites that fail the pre-upgrade check, but I am told those are "relics" from the migration from 2007 to 2010, and that previous CUs and SP1 for SharePoint 2010 installed on this farm without any issues.

We are running the following PSCONFIG command:

```
PSCONFIG.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -wait
```

Any thoughts on how this environment can be salvaged? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, those old "relics" I mentioned ended up being the problem after all (never mind the fact that this farm had successfully been upgraded to 2010, then 2010 SP1). Those 3 sites still held references to an old farm solution that apparently did not fully clean up after itself when it was uninstalled. Once we went in and "brute force removed" all traces of the solution from the farm (to include deleting the 14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES subdirectory for that solution as well as its assembly in the GAC), the upgrade succeeded. We DID have to clear the configuration cache on each server as well as [toggle a property so that PSCONFIG didn't think an upgrade session was already in progress](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288357%28v=office.12%29.aspx), but we are now good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-try running the psconfig first on CA Server/App Server and then other servers which is WFEs.

Comment: Unfortunately, same issue.

Comment: Can you pls clear the cache on each servers. You can follow this step :
1. Stop Windows SharePoint Services Timer on Windows Services
2. Go to ‘C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config’ on front-end server
3. Clear xml files from the above folder.
4. Open cache.ini file and restart the number into ‘1’
5. Start Windows SharePoint Services Timer on Windows Services